Intercepting and redirecting fcntl calls
fcntl is defined as a vararg function int fcntl(int fd, int action, ...) which sometimes takes an int arg and sometimes void* arg.
I'd like to write a logging interceptor for this libc function (using dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fcntl")).
The culprit is that the arg type sizeof for int and void* might not match - so we can't just va_arg and pass it down. How to write such an interceptor correctly and properly and redirect to the libc's underlying orig_fcntl (loaded with dlsym)?
Thanks!

how about using strace? It already exists and does that https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/8399328f628182cf236a1c39a074d601babdeaa4/src/fcntl.c#L102 .

You might want to look at the implementation of fcntl(), to see how it passes the arg to the driver function.

If your system passes int and void* arguments in the same register, you might be able to get away with a hack that pretends that the prototype is int fcntl(int fd, int action, void *arg).  I've never seen that fail when intercepting open() as int open(const char *path, int oflag,  mode_t mode); instead of int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);, but in the case of open() the vararg is always the same type.

Most systems pass int and void * identically (compatibly) as long as it is one of the first ~5 arguments.  Systems like x86_64 and 64 bit RISC (ARM, RISCV64, ALPHA, SPARC, etc) will pass them in 64-bit registers.  32-bit and 16-bit systems generally have them the same size.


How to write such an interceptor correctly and properly and redirect to the libc's underlying orig_fcntl (loaded with dlsym)?

The actual implementation has to accept either argument. On most systems it will be passed in the same register (or the same stack slot) for either type, and so you can use Andrew Henle's solution: pretend that the last argument is a void *arg, and pass that to the original fcntl.
If you are on a system where the ABI specifies different way to pass an argument to variadic function depending on its type, you'll have to read the ABI specification closely and do what it says.

If I use the void* arg definition and pass down argument as so, and the sizeof(void*) == 8, while sizeof(int) == 4 and if int is provided, wouldn't reading it as void* not cause some access violation? Or is it that because of little-endian, after passing it down as void*, the driver could still read it as int?

@VadimKantorov Both registers and stack-slots are of 64-bit, so this shouldn't be a problem.
